# Loading spring application-*.properties

Tags: spring

I was wondering if there is a way to dynamically reference keys in multiple application-*.properties files in a spring application. The challenge I have is the property file names can be different for each app. I have tried various combinations of spring.config.location, spring.config.name, used ClassPathResource but no luck

For e.g. in src/main/resources I might have for application A  application.properties, application-system-X.properties, application-system-Y.properties

For e.g. in src/main/resources I might have for application B,  application.properties, application-system-P.properties, application-system-Q.properties

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I understand you problem correctly. But in Spring Boot you can dynamically use different `application-*.properties` by using profiles.

These [profile-specific application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties) can live inside and outside of your packaged jar (`application-{profile}.properties` and YAML variants).

I can also recommend to read the [documentation on externalising your configuration with Spring Boot](http://%20https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).